# Create categories based on Partial Values Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hi I have a data frame as below:

```
response                         ticket
so service reset performed        123
reboot  done                      343
restart performed                 223
no value                          444
ticket created                    765
```

Im trying something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Downloads\response.xlsx')
print (df)
count_other = 0
othersvocab = ['Service reset' , 'Reboot' , 'restart']

if df.response = othersvocab
{
count_other = count_other + 1
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get the count of how many have either of 'othersvocab' and how many don't.
I'm really new to Python, and I'm not sure how to do this.

Expected Output:

```
other          ticketed
 3                2
```

Can you help me figure it out, hopefully with what's happening in your code?

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: done @MayankPorwal

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below `df`:

```
In [744]: df = pd.DataFrame({'response':['so service reset performed', 'reboot  done', 'restart performed', 'no value', 'ticket created'], 'ticket':[123, 343, 223, 444, 765]})

In [745]: df
Out[745]: 
                     response  ticket
0  so service reset performed     123
1                reboot  done     343
2           restart performed     223
3                    no value     444
4              ticket created     765
```

Below is your `othersvocab`:

```
In [727]: othersvocab = ['Service reset' , 'Reboot' , 'restart']

# Converting all elements to lowercase
In [729]: othersvocab = [i.lower() for i in othersvocab]
```

Use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
# Converting response column to lowercase
In [733]: df.response = df.response.str.lower() 

In [740]: count_in_vocab = len(df[df.response.str.contains('|'.join(othersvocab))])
    
In [742]: count_others = len(df) - count_in_vocab

In [752]: res = pd.DataFrame({'other': [count_in_vocab], 'ticketed': [count_others]})

In [753]: res
Out[753]: 
   other  ticketed
0      3         2
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this on lunch break, I don't like the `for other in others` thing I have and there are better ways using pandas DataFrame methods you can use but it will have to do.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"response": ["so service reset performed", "reboot  done", 
"restart performed"],
                   "ticket": [123, 343, 223]})

others = ['service reset' , 'reboot' , 'restart']

count_other = 0
for row in df["response"].values:
    for other in others:
        if other in row:
            count_other += 1
```

So first you are going to need to address that if you want to perform this in the way I have you're going to have to lowercase the `response` column and the `others` variable, that's not very hard (lookup for pandas apply and the string operator .lower).

1. What I have done in this is I am looping first over the values in the loop column.
2. Then within this loop I am looping over the `others` list items.
3. Finally seeing whether any of these is in the list.

I hope my rushed response gives a hand.